# How to hide and show points on a line graph

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to hide and show points on my line chart when I click on the text of my legend. Here is the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/m6tg4krn/) to my current fiddle. From my fiddle, my blue line working properly as it is showing and hiding on every click of 'Value'. However, the points are not doing so when I click on 'Point'.

I also tried following the advice in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42404329/d3-js-multiple-line-graph-toggle-dots-on-off) but to no avail. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
    var data = [ {x: 0, y: 0}, {x: 5, y: 30}, {x: 10, y: 40},
                {x: 15, y: 60}, {x: 20, y: 70}, {x: 25, y: 100} ];

    const margin = {
      left: 20,
      right: 20,
      top: 20,
      bottom: 80
    };

    const svg = d3.select('svg');
    svg.selectAll("*").remove();

    const width = 200 - margin.left - margin.right;
    const height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    const g = svg.append('g').attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);


    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.x; })])
            .range([0,width])
            .nice();

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.y; })])
            .range([0,height])
            .nice();

    const xAxis = d3.axisTop()
                .scale(x)
                .ticks(5)
                .tickPadding(5)
                .tickSize(-height)

    const yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
                .scale(y)
                .ticks(5)
                .tickPadding(5)
                .tickSize(-width);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", `translate(20,${height-margin.top-60})`)
      .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(20,20)")
      .call(yAxis);

    var lineFunction = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) {return x(d.x); })
    .y(function(d) {return y(d.y); })
    .curve(d3.curveLinear);

    //defining and plotting the lines
    var path = g.append("path")
                .attr("class", "path1")
                .attr("id", "blueLine")
                .attr("d", lineFunction(data))
                .attr("stroke", "blue")
                .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                .attr("fill", "none")
                .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

          // plot a circle at each data point
          g.selectAll(".dot")
              .data(data)
              .enter().append("circle")
              .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.x); } )
              .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.y); } )
              .attr("r", 3)
              .attr("class", "blackDot")
              .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

      //************* Legend ***************
      var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
              .data(data)
              .enter().append("g")

            legend.append("rect")
              .attr("x", width + 65)
              .attr("y", 50)
              .attr("width", 18)
              .attr("height", 4)
              .style("fill", "blue")

            legend.append("text")
              .attr("x", width + 60)
              .attr("y", 50)
              .attr("dy", ".35em")
              .style("text-anchor", "end")
              .on("click", function(){
              // Determine if current line is visible
              var active   = blueLine.active ? false : true,
                newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
              // Hide or show the elements
              d3.select("#blueLine").style("opacity", newOpacity);
              // Update whether or not the elements are active
              blueLine.active = active;
              })
                .text(function(d) {
                  return "Value";
                });

      var pointLegend = svg.selectAll(".pointLegend")
              .data(data)
              .enter().append("g")

            pointLegend.append("circle")
              .attr("r", 3)
              .attr("cx", width + 70)
              .attr("cy", 70)

            pointLegend.append("text")
              .attr("x", width + 60)
              .attr("y", 70)
              .attr("dy", ".35em")
              .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .on("click", function(){
            // Determine if dots are visible
            var active   = blackDot.active ? false : true,
              newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
            // Hide or show the elements
            d3.selectAll(".blackDot").style("opacity", newOpacity);
            // Update whether or not the elements are active
            blackDot.active = active;
            })
              .text(function(d) {
                return "Point";
              });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the way you track the clicked state. Specifically, this variable for the line...

```
//Determine if current line is visible
var active = blueLine.active ? false : true;
```

... and this variable for the circles:

```
// Determine if dots are visible
var active = blackDot.active ? false : true;
```

The line (actually, a `<path>` element) has an id named `blueLine`. Because of that, the element itself is a property of the `window` object, that is, a global variable. For instance, have a look at this:

```js
console.log(window.foo)
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Thus, `blueLine.active` works, even if you never declared `blueLine` anywhere in the code.

However, while the line has an id, your circle's don't (be it `blackDot` or not). Also, the line in question is **just one** and therefore can have an id, but you have **several circles** and, because of that, an id cannot be used (more on that below).

So, the solution is tracking the clicked state another way. For instance, using a property of the datum:

```
.on("click", function(d){
    // Determine if dots are visible
    var active   = d.active ? false : true;
```

Here is the code with that change:

```js
var data = [{
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  }, {
    x: 5,
    y: 30
  }, {
    x: 10,
    y: 40
  },
  {
    x: 15,
    y: 60
  }, {
    x: 20,
    y: 70
  }, {
    x: 25,
    y: 100
  }
];

const margin = {
  left: 20,
  right: 20,
  top: 20,
  bottom: 80
};

const svg = d3.select('svg');
svg.selectAll("*").remove();

const width = 200 - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const g = svg.append('g').attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);


var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })])
  .range([0, width])
  .nice();

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })])
  .range([0, height])
  .nice();

const xAxis = d3.axisTop()
  .scale(x)
  .ticks(5)
  .tickPadding(5)
  .tickSize(-height)

const yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(y)
  .ticks(5)
  .tickPadding(5)
  .tickSize(-width);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", `translate(20,${height-margin.top-60})`)
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(20,20)")
  .call(yAxis);

var lineFunction = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.x);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.y);
  })
  .curve(d3.curveLinear);

//defining and plotting the lines
var path = g.append("path")
  .attr("class", "path1")
  .attr("id", "blueLine")
  .attr("d", lineFunction(data))
  .attr("stroke", "blue")
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

// plot a circle at each data point
g.selectAll(".dot")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return x(d.x);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return y(d.y);
  })
  .attr("r", 3)
  .attr("class", "blackDot")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

//************* Legend ***************
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")

legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width + 65)
  .attr("y", 50)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 4)
  .style("fill", "blue")

legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width + 60)
  .attr("y", 50)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .on("click", function() {
    // Determine if current line is visible
    var active = blueLine.active ? false : true,
      newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
    // Hide or show the elements
    d3.select("#blueLine").style("opacity", newOpacity);
    // Update whether or not the elements are active
    blueLine.active = active;
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return "Value";
  });

var pointLegend = svg.selectAll(".pointLegend")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")

pointLegend.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 3)
  .attr("cx", width + 70)
  .attr("cy", 70);

pointLegend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width + 60)
  .attr("y", 70)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .on("click", function(d) {
    // Determine if dots are visible
    var active = d.active ? false : true,
      newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
    // Hide or show the elements
    d3.selectAll(".blackDot").style("opacity", newOpacity);
    // Update whether or not the elements are active
    d.active = active;
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return "Point";
  });
```

```css
.xy_chart {
  position: relative;
  left: 50px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg class="xy_chart"></svg>
```

Bear in mind that, while setting a single id to several elements is **not advisable**, it will work, as you can see in the demo below, where I just take your code as it is and set the `blackDot` id to the circles:

```js
var data = [{
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  }, {
    x: 5,
    y: 30
  }, {
    x: 10,
    y: 40
  },
  {
    x: 15,
    y: 60
  }, {
    x: 20,
    y: 70
  }, {
    x: 25,
    y: 100
  }
];

const margin = {
  left: 20,
  right: 20,
  top: 20,
  bottom: 80
};

const svg = d3.select('svg');
svg.selectAll("*").remove();

const width = 200 - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const g = svg.append('g').attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);


var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })])
  .range([0, width])
  .nice();

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })])
  .range([0, height])
  .nice();

const xAxis = d3.axisTop()
  .scale(x)
  .ticks(5)
  .tickPadding(5)
  .tickSize(-height)

const yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(y)
  .ticks(5)
  .tickPadding(5)
  .tickSize(-width);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", `translate(20,${height-margin.top-60})`)
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(20,20)")
  .call(yAxis);

var lineFunction = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.x);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.y);
  })
  .curve(d3.curveLinear);

//defining and plotting the lines
var path = g.append("path")
  .attr("class", "path1")
  .attr("id", "blueLine")
  .attr("d", lineFunction(data))
  .attr("stroke", "blue")
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

// plot a circle at each data point
g.selectAll(".dot")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return x(d.x);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return y(d.y);
  })
  .attr("r", 3)
  .attr("id", "blackDot")
  .attr("class", "blackDot")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

//************* Legend ***************
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")

legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width + 65)
  .attr("y", 50)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 4)
  .style("fill", "blue")

legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width + 60)
  .attr("y", 50)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .on("click", function() {
    // Determine if current line is visible
    var active = blueLine.active ? false : true,
      newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
    // Hide or show the elements
    d3.select("#blueLine").style("opacity", newOpacity);
    // Update whether or not the elements are active
    blueLine.active = active;
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return "Value";
  });

var pointLegend = svg.selectAll(".pointLegend")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")

pointLegend.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 3)
  .attr("cx", width + 70)
  .attr("cy", 70)

pointLegend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width + 60)
  .attr("y", 70)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .on("click", function() {
    // Determine if dots are visible
    var active = blackDot.active ? false : true,
      newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
    // Hide or show the elements
    d3.selectAll(".blackDot").style("opacity", newOpacity);
    // Update whether or not the elements are active
    blackDot.active = active;
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return "Point";
  });
```

```css
.xy_chart {
  position: relative;
  left: 50px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg class="xy_chart"></svg>
```

But, again, it's not recommended setting the same id to several elements: ids must be unique.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! I thought setting an id for the dots wouldn't have worked which is why I didn't try it in the first place thus I set a class for the dots instead. Apparently it will work as well but now I know it is not advisable to do so as ids must be unique and I should use the property of datum instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [this example](https://github.com/bradparks/d3-Simple-Line-Graph-with-Points-and-Tooltip-Hoverstate/blob/master/index.html).

note the : .style("visibility", "hidden") in tooltip options.